# Not able to understand why let variable name is throwing error

Tags: javascript

This example is taken from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Another_example_of_temporal_dead_zone_combined_with_lexical_scoping) and it throws error because

> The instruction let n of n.a is already inside the private scope of
>   the for loop's block, hence the identifier "n.a" is resolved to the
>   property 'a' of the 'n' object located in the first part of the
>   instruction itself **("let n"), which is still in the temporal dead zone**
>   since its declaration statement has not been reached and terminated.

```js
function go(n) {
  for (let n of n.a) {
    console.log(n);
  }
}

go({
  a: [1, 2, 3]
});
```

Now I changed the variable name from `n` to `k` and it works. But according to `mdn` `let k` will be still in temporal dead zone. **Then how come this does not throws the error but logs the value?**

```js
function go(n) {
  for (let k of n.a) {
    console.log(k);
  }
}

go({
  a: [1, 2, 3]
});
```

Comment: in `let k` you not shadowing the `n` parameter at `go(n)`

Answer (score 2):

> But according to mdn `let k` will be still in temporal dead zone.

No, by the time you've used it in your code (`console.log(k)`), it's been initialized with the value being iterated for that loop. It's not in the TDZ anymore.

The TDZ problem with the `let n` version is here:

```
for (let n of n.a) {
// -----------^
```

At that point, the `n` declared with `let` has shadowed the `n` parameter. It's reserved and in the TDZ, but the code is trying to use it (not the `n` parameter) in `of n.a`. That's not a problem with your `k` version, because you don't reference `k` there.

Comment: but ... why? Couldn't the right side of the `for..of` just be  executed in the parent scope?

Comment: @JonasWilms - It *could*, but it would be confusing. It's a simpler mental model if `for (let n of n.a)` and `let n = n.a` behave the same way in terms of what the `n` in `n.a` is.

Comment: jup, just read through the spec, and the right side gets executed inside another local scope, named *TDZ* which makes the purpose quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let n of n.a) {
//         ^^^^^^
```

The temporal dead zone of this statement is the underlined `of n.a` part. Since it contains a reference to `n`, the variable being declared (by `let n`), this is an error.

```
for (let k of n.a) {
//         ^^^^^^
```

In this example the temporal dead zone still consists of `n.a`, but we're now declaring a different variable, `k`. Since the expression in the dead zone doesn't use `k`, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is a ReferenceError in the first case because the spec wants to prevent confusion if a variable name is used on both sides of the `of`. In theory even the first version could work, then this:

```
 for(let n of n.a) { /*body*/ }
```

could be executed as:

```
 const iterator = n.a[Symbol.iterator](); // the iterator is initialized in the parent scope
 let done = true;
 while(!done) {
   let n;
   ({ value: n, done } = iterator.next()); // "n" is initialized in the local loop scope.
   /* body */
 }
```

But as that would create confusion if `n.a` on the right side would not refer to the `n` on the left-side, the authors of the spec added another scope, to prevent that variables of the loop are used in the iterator: All local variables also get declared in another scope, that is only used to initialize the iterator:

```
 { // another local scope (named TDZ in the spec)
   const iterator = n.a[Symbol.iterator](); // "n" cannot be used here, as it was not yet initialized
   let done = false;

   let n; // this is just to prevent "n" from being used in the line above

    while(!done) {
       let n;
       ({ value: n, done } = iterator.next());
    }
 }
```

Relevant section of the spec:

> **13.7.5.12 Runtime Semantics: ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation**
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>  b. Let TDZ be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
>
>  [...]
>
>  d. For each string name in TDZnames, do
>
>    i. Perform ! TDZEnvRec.CreateMutableBinding(name, false).
>
>  e. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to TDZ.
>
> 3. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating expr
> ```

whereas *expr* is `n.a` in this case, and *TDZnames* contains `n`.

Answer (score 0):

The "n being in TDZ" refers to the second n in the loop declaration, "*let n of **n**.a*". With *"for (let k of n.a)"* that problem doesn't exist: the only time *k* is referenced is inside the loop.